# Changing the data type of values in the Django model

Tags: django, pandas, dataframe, django-models

I have data which is loaded into a dataframe. This dataframe then needs to be saved to a django model. The major problem is that some data which should go into `IntegerField` or `FloatField` are empty strings `""`. On the other side, some data which should be saved into a `CharField` is represented as `np.nan`.  This leads to the following errors:

> ValueError: Field 'position_lat' expected a number but got nan.

If I replace the np.nan with an empty string, using `data[database]["df"].replace(np.nan, "", regex = True, inplace = True)`, I end up with the following error:

> ValueError: Field 'position_lat' expected a number but got ''.

So what I would like to do, is to check in the model whether a `FloatField` or `IntegerField` gets either `np.nan` or an empty string and replace it with an empty value. The same for `CharField`, which should convert integers (if applicable) to strings or `np.nan` to an empty string.

How could this be implemented? Using ModelManager or customized fields? Or any better approaches? Sorting the CSV files out is not an option.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from .models import Record

my_dataframe = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
record = Record

entries = []
    for e in my_dataframe.T.to_dict().values():
        entries.append(record(**e))
    record.objects.bulk_create(entries)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem was not clear, nevertheless, I would like to post my solution. I create a new `dict` which only contain keys with corresponding values.

```
entries = []
for e in my_dataframe.T.to_dict().values():
    e = {k: v for k, v in e.items() if v}
    entries.append(record(**e))
record.objects.bulk_create(entries)
```

Comment: Why `e = {k: v for k, v in e.items() if v}`?